# Filling up spaces using $0$'s and $1$'s

Tags: combinatorics

Original question: [image]

***According to the given question, I think that it can be reframed into—***

Given $12$ places which can be filled up with $\text{E,L}$ such that there are a  total of $6 \text { E}$ and $6$ $\text {L}$. If for every $n$ $\text {L}$'s, there has to be $\geq$ $n$ $\text {E}$'s; $n\in \mathbb{N}$, find the total numbers of ways the $12$ spaces can be filled up.

***Explanation of what I meant :***

If there are 3 E's then, there can be no more than 3 L's before another E appears in the sequence. Like, EEELLEL....(this may be possible) but EELLLLEE....(this isn't possible). Let E denote then entry of a car into an in Incoming Railway Track leading to a shunting yard and L denotes the exit from the Outgoing Track. If in the shunting yard 3 cars get inside, then, there can be at most 3 exits. That's the thing.

I noted that the first and the last blanks will be $\text {E}$ and $\text {L}$ respectively.

***The answer given is $30$. Please check if I'm in the correct path***

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that for every n L's there are at least n E's.  (Could you give examples when, say, there are 6 places with 3 E's and 3 L's.)

Comment: @user84413 edited and added explanation

Comment: You should not change a question after it has been answered.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I'm sorry, I understand the work out by you.